# fibonacci implementation in prolog

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I'm trying to make my own implementation of the fibonacci sequence. This is what I have:

```
fibo2(N, F) :-
    fibo2(0, 1, 0, N, F).

fibo2(N-F, F, N-1, N, F).

fibo2(P, S, C, N, F) :-
    C < N,
    T is S,
    S1 is P + S,
    C1 is C + 1,
    fibo2(T, S1, C1, N, F).
```

I know there are other implementations but I dont know why this isnt working. When I do a trace with `fibo2(3, 2)` I think this call should throw true:

```
fibo2(1, 2, 2, 3, 2) ? creep
```

But it returns false... Some help would be appreciated

Comment: you should include short comments with your code, explaining what each variable is supposed to be, and what is the purpose of each predicate. At least `"fibo2(N, F):-  % F is N-th Fibonacci number, indexed base 1"` should have been there.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `T is S` line serves no purpose. When you do not need to perform arithmetic, prefer the use of standard unification with `(=)/2`. Here, you could directly call `fibo2(S, S1, C1, N, F)`.

Then, your recursion has no base case. The first clause of `fibo2/5` will never be true here.

You certainly meant:

```
fibo2(P, S, C, N, F) :-
    P is N - F,
    S is F,
    C is N - 1.
```

Here arithmetic will be performed (when doing unification in the head, arithmetic is not performed, manipulation are entirely symbolic).

I'm not sure what your `N` and `F` stand for so I won't comment your code further, but that should fix some problems already.

Comment: greetings! :) `fibo2(N, F) :- fibo2(0, 1, 0, N, F).` so `N,F` can be vars, so they must go to the left of `is`; so the re-write of the 1st clause should be: `fibo2(P, S, C, N, F) :- F=S, N is P+F, C is N-1.` :) { `P` = "previous"; `S` is a mystery; `C` is probably "count", and `F` - the `N`-th Fibonacci number }, is my guess. :)